# Dynamic GUI in Python?

Tags: python, dynamic, user-interface

I had a question about whether it would be possible to make something like the following in Python:

I'd like to have a GUI such that, upon starting there are simply two fields allowing you load two particular files.

When those files have been selected it parses and displays the contents, and dynamically generates a set of checkboxes to allow the user to select or not options based on the content of the file.

Is such a thing possible in Python, or would i need to look elsewhere?

Cheers
Lindley

Comment: The answer is yes, it's possible in Python.

Comment: There are a variety of python (as well as non-python) tool kits that can let you build GUI's on the fly.  Pygtk would be the one I've used most frequently, although I haven't actually used it recently enough to be able to whip out example code.

Comment: its also possible in php, js, java , c#, c++ , c , fortran, lisp, matlab, and pretty much any language you want ...

Answer (score 1):

At least three ways of doing this:

1. [Gi](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) (GTK with Python) (The API here is for the C language, but
   is the same more or less for Python)
2. [PyQt](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/)
3. [Tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter)

Comment: also wxPython , simplegui, pygame, pyglet, .... ,lots of ways